# looping into nested array and modify data

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

As per the above structure, All the types are having `text-1`.

I wanted only the first occurrence to be in `text-1` rest all should be of `text-2` in the `data structure`.

And the order of the block should not be changed. Also block can have different types which should not get affected.

I tried to loop each block, but dono the logic to modify only first occurrence.  Please help

Below is what i tried so far,

```
let newData = data.forEach(data => {
  return data.block.forEach(block => {
    return block.child.forEach((type, i) => {
      if (i === 0) { return }
      type.type = 'text-2'
    })
  });
});
```

**Current Data**

```
const data = [
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }
    ]
  },
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Data,**

```
const data = [
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-2' }] }
    ]
  },
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-2' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-2' }] }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The logic behind the transformation doesn't seem that reasonable, to me.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's what needed :|

Comment: @user007 ok, so may you show us at least what you've tried to accomplish such? the question sounds like "please do that for me", which is not that reasonable as well ;)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my code. I thought why posting the code which dosen't  work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the items and the nested ones as well by taking a function for getting the first string once and for all other calls the other string.

```js
const
    getOnce = (first, other, used) => () => used ? other : (used = true, first);
    data = [{ block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }, { block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }],
    type1 = 'text-1',
    type2 = 'text-2',
    getType = getOnce(type1, type2),
    result = data.map(
        ({ block }) => ({
            block: block.map(
                ({ child }) => ({
                    child: child.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, o.type === type1 && { type: getType() }))
                })
            )
        })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: beautiful usage of array operators, as always. I'm just wondering whether OP wants a new array or wants to alter the original one.

Comment: @nina - Your solutions works perfect, But only one issue. My datastructure will have other items also in root level like `metadata`, `seo`, Now it's only returning the `content` part alone. Please check this stackBlitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bdryis?file=index.ts . Can you please help me to return the full result with your logic in place

Comment: why not assign the result back to `data.data.content`?

Answer (score 1):

Generic alternative using the [`JSON.parse` revival parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) :

```js
var found = 0, data = [{ block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }, { block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }]

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data), 
              (key, val) => key == 'type' && val == 'text-1' && found++ ? 'text-2' : val)

console.log( data )
```

---

Mutating alternative with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) :

```js
const data = [{ block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }, { block: [{ child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }, { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }] }];
let found = 0;

for (const item of data)
  for (const block of item.block)
    for (const child of block.child)
      if (child.type === 'text-1' && found++)
        child.type = 'text-2';

console.log( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- The array structure is the one shown in the example.
- every `data` element is an object.

  - every object has a block property and it's an array.
  - every block element **might** have a type property.
- **you want to alter the original array without making a new copy of it** (that's what I've understood from the question, but I can be wrong, of course).

Here is an (ugly) solution to alter the values as required.

As a side note, this kind of alteration is weird and doesn't really seems to make much sense, I **highly** recommend you to consider using alternative data structures.

Code explanation is directly in the code below.

```js
const data = [
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'any type' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }
    ]
  },
  {
    block: [
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] },
      { child: [{ type: 'text-1' }] }
    ]
  }
];

// That's unreasonable.. anyway.
data.forEach((o, i) => {
  // loop each element, keep track of the index.
  if (i > 0) {
    // if it's NOT the first element, get all the elements who actually have a child, loop the child and for each type property, replace 1 with 2.
    o.block.forEach(c => c.child && c.child.forEach(child => child.type = child.type.replace("1","2")));
  }
  else {
    // otherwise, if that's the first element, just find the last block that has a child and whose child equals 'text-1'.
    const elems = o.block.filter(c => c.child && c.child.length && c.child.some(child => child.type === 'text-1'));
    const found = elems && elems.length && elems[elems.length - 1];
    // if found, replace the value.
    if (found) found.child[0].type = found.child[0].type.replace("1","2");
  }
});

console.log(data);
```